# AJAX Accordion with Required Field Validators Collapses

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have looked for hours on this but not found an answer. Please help.

I have an accordion on my page and in the first pane i have placed a textbox with a required field validator.

I have added a second pane just with some text.

I would expect to not be able to move to the next pane until i have entered text in the textbox but this does not happen.

Currently if i leave the textbox empty and click on pane 2, pane 2 expands and pane 1 collapses but the required field validator does run and shows the error message.

How can i prevent the pane from changing until i have entered the text in pane 1?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" CodeBehind="Create.aspx.vb" Inherits="Concerns_2_0.Create" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<h2>Create Concern</h2>
<hr />
<asp:Panel ID="CreatePnl" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Acc1" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="AccHead" ContentCssClass="AccCont" SelectedIndex="0" >
                <Panes>
                    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="ChoicePane" runat="server" >
                        <Header>
                            <asp:Button ID="Pane0Btn" runat="server" CssClass="panebtn" Text="Concern Type" />
                        </Header>
                        <Content>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="reqtxt" runat="server" ValidationGroup="grp1"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="reqtxt" ErrorMessage="Required!" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="grp1"  />
                        </Content>
                    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
                    <ajaxToolKit:AccordionPane ID="InvoicePane" runat="server">
                        <Header>
                            <asp:Button ID="Pane1Btn" runat="server" CssClass="panebtn" Text="Search For Invoice" />
                        </Header>
                        <Content>
                            test content 2
                        </Content>
                    </ajaxToolKit:AccordionPane>
                </Panes>
            </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Also, my script manager is on the master page.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `RequiredFieldValidator`s are usually triggered when a page/form is submitted, not when you move around the page. You'll have to add some custom javascript to get what you need. (If it's possible. I'm not sure if you can lock someone in a field. I guess you'll have to check the field every time they try to exit the field and return the cursor there.)